# WinZip Command Line File Release

Tags: batch-file, winzip

I'm using WZUNZIP.exe to unzip a file in a batch mode, but often it would not release the zip file after it's done, causing the program hang or not to run the next scheduled time. Is there any "exit" or "quit" commands that I can insert after the main command?
In a nutshell: I grab a zip file from an FTP, then extract its content into the correct folder, then delete the zip file. Do it daily. It appears to me that WinZip keeps a hold on the file after it's done. What can I do.

Here is my code, as simple as that:

```
    REM ***  Run FTP-import routine
C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe  -s:C:\FTP_Temp\FtpImport.txt

    REM ***  Unzip
cd C:\Program Files\WinZip
wzunzip  -o    C:\FTP_Temp\myArchive.zip    K:\myPath\myFiles

    REM ***  Delete downloaded zip
cd C:\FTP_Temp
Del c:\FTP_Temp\myArchive.zip
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? It would be useful to see the batch code you're running.

Comment: You could copy the file after it arrives and wzunzip the copy - but I doubt it is wzunzip holding the file - possibly an automatic virus-checker.

Comment: @ManoDestra - Thanks. I added my simple code.